# Does Robocopy SKIP copying existing files by default?

Tags: windows, robocopy

I've *read* (somewhere) that [Robocopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) skips copying over existing files by default.

But... I can't find any Command Line [switches](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for that.

Comment: If the program behaves a certain why by default, this means that no switches are required to invoke that particular behavior.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default, Robocopy skips copying existing files ***if the specific metadata of the files match*** then those files ***will be skipped*** from the "file" copy operation (`/COPY:DAT`).

> **Robocopy Defaults**
>
> - Skips file copy if last write time, file name, **and** file size match
> - Copies file if last write time, file name, **or** file sizes don't match

As indicated by [@mklement0](https://superuser.com/users/139307/mklement0), the **implied default `/COPY:DAT`** will not copy over files with different data if the timestamp [LastWriteTime] and the file size is the same and thus this is a default skip.

So if for some reason you have two files you are syncing that have matching file size, file name, and last modified attributes even though the data is different, it will not copy the source file.

> **Robocopy Default Options:** `/COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30`

As confirmed by log file or command window running **`robocopy c:\source c:\dest *`**

---

### [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) or Robocopy /?

```
 /COPY:copyflag[s] : What to COPY (default is /COPY:DAT)
                      (copyflags : D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps
                       S=Security=NTFS ACLs, O=Owner info, U=aUditing info).
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the skip-if-same logic is unrelated to the (implied) `/COPY`  argument. Specifically, only a file's size and its last-modified time stamp ever seem to matter.

Comment: Yes: 2 files that have the same last-modified timestamp and the same file size are considered identical, even if their content differs (an exotic scenario, to be clear). Whatever you pass to `/COPY` doesn't matter in terms of determining sameness - it only applies to what will be copied _if the destination file has been deemed to be different_.

Comment: @mklement0 - Let me ask you this.... if two files are the same size and the same date last modified to the second or microsecond or whatever, what would you recommend the taken action be based on that condition? Should this be "a case by case basis" or should "the default copy to destination"?

Comment: Robocopy's behavior is a reasonable default, given how exotic the scenario I describe is. Nonetheless, sometimes you want to determine sameness (possibly exclusively) based on _content_ - something that Robocopy currently doesn't offer. All of this is incidental to the problem at hand, however: the fact that your explanation based on `/COPY` is a red herring that doesn't describe the actual algorithm Robocopy uses to determine what files to skip, which, as stated, has nothing to do with `/COPY`.

Comment: @mklement0 Okay, so I tested and I confirmed that you are correct the same `$file.FullName.ForEach{(Get-Item $_).LastWriteTime=$(Get-Date)}` for files that are exactly the "same size" and "same file name" with one having `aaaaa2` and the other having `aaaaa5` content are not copied. Using no options with the `Robocopy` command the implied default of `/COPY:DAT` which is accurate does not copy files when the data is different when the timestamp and file size is the same. The default is still `/COPY:DAT` as the documentation states and the output results of the command shows regardless.

Comment: Let me try to phrase it the opposite way: it doesn't matter what you pass to `/COPY` or whether you use the default (`DAT`): The only pieces of metadata that are _invariably_ considered are the last-modified time stamp and the file size. To give a specific example: the default `/COPY` value includes file attributes, yet Robocopy doesn't consult attributes to determine sameness. I believe my answer to tell the full story, and I invite you to vet it.

Answer (score 11):

```
robocopy SOURCE DESTINATION FILE(S) /IS
```

Where `IS` stands for **I**nclude **S**ame file(s). Using this switch causes to overwrite existing files. See below:

```
::
:: File Selection Options :
::
                 /A :: copy only files with the Archive attribute set.
                 /M :: copy only files with the Archive attribute and reset it.
    /IA:[RASHCNETO] :: Include only files with any of the given Attributes set.
    /XA:[RASHCNETO] :: eXclude files with any of the given Attributes set.

 /XF file [file]... :: eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.
 /XD dirs [dirs]... :: eXclude Directories matching given names/paths.

                /XC :: eXclude Changed files.
                /XN :: eXclude Newer files.
                /XO :: eXclude Older files.
                /XX :: eXclude eXtra files and directories.
                /XL :: eXclude Lonely files and directories.
                /IS :: Include Same files.
                /IT :: Include Tweaked files.
```

Answer (score 10):

- Unfortunately, the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) doesn't describe the logic behind **what files are *skipped* by default**.
- The unofficial [ss64.com documentation](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), however, provides the crucial pointer (emphasis added):

  - > By default Robocopy will only copy a file if the source and destination have **different time stamps or different file sizes**.

Note: *time stamp* refers to the ***last-modified* time stamp** (only).

In other words: **Robocopy considers two files to be the *same* based *only* on whether their last-modified time stamps and file sizes are identical and therefore *skips* copying in that event.**

From what I can tell:

- This behavior is *not* affected by modifying *what aspects of a file / directory to copy* (parameters `/copy` / `/dcopy`)

  - These arguments are only applied *if* RoboCopy has fundamentally deemed a given file / directory in need of copying, based on sameness / inclusion logic.
- If you want to ***extend* the default sameness detection** (same last-modified timestamp and same file size) to the **following properties**, use the **`/it` (*Include Tweaked*)** option:

  - file attributes (represented as `A` for the `/copy` parameter)
  - ACL (represented as `S` for the `/copy` parameter)
  - file ownership (represented as `O` for the `/copy` parameter)
  - auditing information (represented as `U` for the `/copy` parameter)
- **Robocopy seems offers *no* option to detect sameness of files based on their *content*** (which is typically implemented via a [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)).
  Therefore, in the **rare event** that there could be **files with identical last-modified time stamps and identical file sizes that nonetheless differ in *content***, your only option is to use the **`/is` (*Include Same*)** option:

  - This causes the files that are considered the same to be copied *unconditionally* - and therefore potentially unnecessarily.
  - **Caveat**: Curiously, files that are the same with respect to last-modified file stamp and file size *but differ with respect to the `/it`-related properties mentioned above* are *not* included by default with `/is` alone; therefore, **to cover all eventualities, use `/is` and `/it` *combined*.**

---

The following [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester) tests demonstrate 
the behaviors; save the code as `Tests.ps1` and invoke it as `Invoke-Pester ./Tests.ps1`:

```powershell
Describe RoboCopySkippedFilesTests {
  BeforeAll {
    Push-Location TestDrive:
  }
  AfterAll {
    Pop-Location
  }
  BeforeEach {
    # Set up a source and a destination folder and make their
    # Content the same.
    if (Test-Path dest) { Remove-Item -Force -Recurse dest }
    $null = New-Item -Type Directory -Force src
    'file1' > src\file1
    'file2' > src\file2
    Copy-Item -Recurse src dest
  }

  It "Does not copy anything with identical folders." {
    robocopy.exe src dest
    $LASTEXITCODE | Should Be 0
  }
  It "Does recognize a changed last-modified filestamp" {
    (gi src\file1).LastWriteTime = [datetime]::now
    robocopy.exe src dest # | Out-Host
    $LASTEXITCODE | Should Be 1
  }
  It "Does recognize a change in file size" {
    '!' | Add-Content dest\file1
    robocopy.exe src dest # | Out-Host
    $LASTEXITCODE | Should Be 1
  }
  It "Does not recognize a change in file content, with size and last-modified date identical" {
    'file!' > dest\file1
    (Get-Item dest\file1).LastWriteTime = (Get-Item src\file1).LastWriteTime
    robocopy.exe src dest # | Out-Host
    $LASTEXITCODE | Should Be 0
  }
  It "Does not recognize a change in file attributes, with size and last-modified date identical" {
    (Get-Item dest\file1).Attributes = 'System'
    robocopy.exe src dest # | Out-Host
    $LASTEXITCODE | Should Be 0
  }
  It "Does recognize an attribute-modified-only file as tweaked (/IT)" {
    (Get-Item dest\file1).Attributes = 'System'
    robocopy.exe src dest /IT # | Out-Host
    $LASTEXITCODE | Should Be 1
  }
  It "Does not include an attribute-modified-only file with /IS" {
    Remove-Item src\file2, dest\file2
    (Get-Item dest\file1).Attributes = 'System'
    robocopy.exe src dest /IS # | Out-Host
    $LASTEXITCODE | Should Be 0
  }
}
```

You should see something like the following, indicating that all tests passed (as of `Robocopy.exe` with file version `10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)`):

```
Describing RoboCopySkippedFilesTests
 [+] Does not copy anything with identical folders. 231ms
 [+] Does recognize a changed last-modified filestamp 112ms
 [+] Does recognize a change in file size 68ms
 [+] Does not recognize a change in file content, with size and last-modified date identical 69ms
 [+] Does not recognize a change in file attributes, with size and last-modified date identical 83ms
 [+] Does recognize an attribute-modified-only file as tweaked (/IT) 65ms
 [+] Does not include an attribute-modified-only file with /IS 70ms
Tests completed in 589ms
Passed: 7 Failed: 0 Skipped: 0 Pending: 0 Inconclusive: 0
```

Comment: Great info.  I guess the `/is` argument not comparing files before copying makes sense; the overhead of comparing the 2 files' content would likely be as time consuming as copying the file (except in cases where write IO is significantly slower than the network latency between source and destination).