# Robocopy from network drive doesn't skip duplicates

Tags: windows-explorer, cmd.exe, robocopy

This is my robocopy line:

```
robocopy "\\network\Document\Migration" D:\Migration /S
```

As described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1114377/does-robocopy-skip-copying-existing-files-by-default) robocopy should skip files that have the same size, date and name.

### First copy from network to local folder

When I execute the robocopy line the first time all my test files are copied and this is the result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Started : 25 July 2022 13:47:35
   Source = \\network\Document\Migration\
     Dest : d:\Migration\
    Files : *.*
  Options : *.* /S /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          New Dir          3    \\network\Document\Migration\
            New File                   0        file 1.txt
            New File                   0        file 2.txt
            New File                   0        File 3.docx
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Files :         3         3         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
```

### Second copy from network to local folder

Now if I execute the exact same command again without touching the files, the 3 files should be skipped, right? But thats not whats happening. All are copied again and "*EXTRA File" is displayed (only relevant infos this time):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           3    \\network\Document\Migration\
          *EXTRA File                  0        file 1.txt
          *EXTRA File                  0        file 2.txt
          *EXTRA File                  0        File 3.docx
            New File                   0        file 1.txt
            New File                   0        file 2.txt
            New File                   0        File 3.docx

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         3         3         0         0         0         3
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

### First copy from local folder to other local folder

Before writing this Question, I tested the command on 2 local folders with the previous target folder where the 3 test files were copied into as source path and a new target path:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          New Dir          3    d:\Migration\
            New File                   0        file 1.txt
            New File                   0        file 2.txt
            New File                   0        File 3.docx

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Files :         3         3         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

The 3 files were copied as expected.

### Second copy from local to local

When executing this script a second time, this is the full result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 25 July 2022 14:49:13
   Source : d:\Migration\
     Dest : d:\Migration2\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           3    d:\Migration\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         3         0         3         0         0         0
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Ended : 25 July 2022 14:49:13
```

As expected, all 3 files were skipped. Why weren't they skipped when I copied them from the Network folder?

They all have the same name, date and size:
[image]
[image: d:\migration]

### Edit file comparison and /FFT

As suggested by @Paul I added the `/FFT` switch but they are still recognized and copied as `*EXTRA File`.
This is the result:

```
Options : *.* /FFT /V /S /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           3    \\network\Document\Migration\
          *EXTRA File                  0        file 1.txt
          *EXTRA File                  0        file 2.txt
          *EXTRA File                  0        File 3.docx
            New File                   0        file 1.txt
            New File                   0        file 2.txt
            New File                   0        File 3.docx

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         3         3         0         0         0         3
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
```

#### File comparison

With fc I compared file contents but for all 3 of them "no differences encountered"

```
C:\Users\username>fc "\\network\Document\Migration\file 1.txt" "d:\migration\file 1.txt"
Comparing files \\NETWORK\DOCUMENT\MIGRATION\FILE 1.TXT and D:\MIGRATION\FILE 1.TXT
FC: no differences encountered
```

And with robocopy (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29575698/9013718)) I only displayed the file metadata and name:

```
robocopy "\\network\Document\Migration" d:\migration /l /ts /nc /ndl /njh /njs /FFT

                               0 2022/07/25 11:31:55    d:\migration\file 1.txt
                               0 2022/07/25 11:32:06    d:\migration\file 2.txt
                               0 2022/07/25 11:32:18    d:\migration\File 3.docx
                               0 2022/07/25 11:31:55    \\network\Document\Migration\file 1.txt
                               0 2022/07/25 11:32:06    \\network\Document\Migration\file 2.txt
                               0 2022/07/25 11:32:18    \\network\Document\Migration\File 3.docx
```

I can't find a difference! (The time is 2h less than what it displays on my Windows Explorer but it's consistent, so I think this is not a relevant detail).
They are clearly considered as different by robocopy and I don't know how to find out the difference or why it does see them as not similar.

When I do the same command on my two local folders `robocopy d:\migration d:\migration2 /l /ts /nc /ndl /njh /njs` no result is coming and this is good because there is not the switch `/is` which stands for "*Includes the same files.*".
Even without the `/is`, it displays all file infos on the network / local folder command. They are not the same for robocopy... but why?

#### Edit - `/mir` at the end

So as suggested I executed the following command without `/is` to make sure only files that would be copied are displayed and not all.

```
robocopy "\\network\Document\Migration" d:\migration /l /ts /nc /ndl /njh /njs /FFT /mir
```

This is the result:

```
                               0 2022/07/25 11:31:55    d:\migration\file 1.txt
                               0 2022/07/25 11:32:06    d:\migration\file 2.txt
                               0 2022/07/25 11:32:18    d:\migration\File 3.docx
                               0 2022/07/25 11:31:55    \\network\Document\Migration\file 1.txt
                               0 2022/07/25 11:32:06    \\network\Document\Migration\file 2.txt
                               0 2022/07/25 11:32:18    \\network\Document\Migration\File 3.docx
```

It's exactly the same as without `/fft` or `/mir`.

Comment: Try to keep `/fft`, and add `/mir` to the *end* of the command.

Comment: The result is exactly the same as without any of them. I added more details and the full command in another edit.

Comment: What's is the operating system and the file-system on the remote computer?

Comment: Is there a way I can know this on my end? It is the "old" system of a customer, and the software manufacturer is not collaborating well. I know it is a Microsoft Dynamics 365 application version 1612 though if that helps.

Comment: Whatever is this remote file-system, it seems that files are never identical. Try the argument `/copy:DT /dcopy:DT` to exclude copying attributes. If this doesn't work, maybe you should consider a third-party sync product.

Comment: I have to ask, does RoboCopy have Hashing features? You can (should but depends who you're asking) compare hashes instead of those `never constant` variables such as file size (depends on block size) date (write? modify? create? date) and name (of course, name can always change despite files being equal).

Answer (score 2):

This may be caused by discrepancies in timestamps between the two systems.
You could try to add the /FFT flag, which makes Robocopy more tolerant (it uses a two-second resolution). Also, you chould add the /V (verbose) flag to get more information about what is going on.

Comment: Adding both did nothing. They're still copied as "*EXTRA File"

Comment: This surely is file system issue. Maybe one is exFAT with less resolution for timestamp.