# ROBOCOPY how to exclude existing files by name only

Tags: windows, robocopy

Here ([Does Robocopy SKIP copying existing files by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/1114377/does-robocopy-skip-copying-existing-files-by-default)) it says ROBOCOPY will by default overwrite files if they differ by name or last write date or size.

However I am looking for a ROBOCOPY switch(s) that will not overwrite destination files that have the same name *regardless* of any other attribute (size, date, etc)

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch you can use is /XN, which stands for "eXclude Newer." When you use this switch, Robocopy will skip copying files that already exist in the destination and have the same name, regardless of any other attribute.

> ```
>   ROBOCOPY source destination /XN
> ```

By using /XN, Robocopy will only copy files that are not already present in the destination. Any files with the same name in the destination will be skipped.